# Ubuntu copying files inside a folder to a new folder

Tags: ubuntu, recursion, cp

I want to copy the contents of a folder ( not the folder itself) to another folder in ubuntu. Is there anyway to do it with cp command? cp always also move the source folder too

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To move contents of a folder to another in Linux systems the simplest way to do that is to use cp command.

1, Example of coping all contents that are in the `oldFolder`  to the `newFolder`

`cp -r ./oldFolder/* ./newFolder/`

2,  Copy only one file from the `oldFolder` to `newFolder`

`cp -r ./oldFolder/file.txt ./newFolder/`